# How to parse xml and filter content in php via DOMXPath::query

Tags: php

XML file link here :-

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9NYyX8V32BmM0JsbkNYZW9tLWM/view?usp=sharing

```
I want to filter only crucial details from the data .
```

My code does not generate any output on screen.

```
//demo.php
<?php    
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;    
$doc->load('settings.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);    
$lineitems = $doc->getElementsByTagName('lineitems')->item(0);
$query = 'lineitem/itemcode';
$entries = $xpath->query($query, $lineitems);
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
echo "Found {$entry->nextSiblings->nodeValue}," .
" by {$entry->previousSibling->nodeValue}\n";
}
?>
```

I am getting blank on screen.

```
output needed:-
ITEMCODE QUANTITY
ITEMCODE QUANTITY
ITEMCODE QUANTITY
ITEMCODE QUANTITY
```

Comment: enable errors http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/391/exception-handling-and-error-reporting/1298/setting-error-reporting-and-where-to-display-them#t=201703150444582524662

Comment: Tried using it still no errors displaying .

Comment: well then, if you are doing it right, and really there are no errors, it means there are no entries. have you tried to verify there are actually entries in your array? something like `var_dump($entries);`?

Comment: i tried before foreach loop, using var_dump it said object(DOMNodeList)#3 (1) { ["length"]=> int(0) }

Comment: so, can you guess what `["length"]=> int(0)` means?

Comment: Not sure about this

Comment: Length means how many elements are present. Int is the shorthand for integer. 0 means... 0. Entries is of length0 : it contains no elements.

Comment: I have added xml on google drive to verify. The elements are 5 in it .

Comment: then you have to fix the way you get the items out of the xml. php is not lying to you. $entries is empty. if the xml is right, then it's the code in between that is wrong. this `getElementsByTagName('lineitems')` is very suspicious. I don't know of any elemtn which is named lineitems, normally it would be 'div' or 'td', like normal html tags.

Comment: $tbody = $doc->getElementsByTagName('LineItems')->item(4);

// our query is relative to the tbody node
$query = 'Lineitem';
var_dump($query);

Comment: output is string(8) "Lineitem"

Comment: Thanks guys i have solved it

Comment: great! if you can, please answer your own question with your solution, then accept it after the needed time passes. that way, this question will not clutter the questions list needlessly. thanks!